# How to play infinitely overlapping sounds?

Tags: iphone, core-audio, audiounit, overlapping

I have a button that triggers a sound on an iphone. I am using AudioUnits to minimize the latency.

Right now, if the user taps the button twice, the sound do not overlap and the first triggered sound is cut by the second sound. Is there an easy way to let the (same) sound overlapping as many times as the user taps the buttons?

Thanks.

André.

Answer (score 4):

Leave the AudioUnit running continuously, using short buffers to minimize latency, and start to mix another copy of the sound into the existing stream every time the button is tapped.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try that. André

Comment: I have completed my programming, using queues for each sound instances. It works really well. Thanks again.